# Solved: How do I properly utilise reactive expressions to get this plot to work in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

## Problem

Hi, very new to RShiny (though not R) and I'm trying to write a simple application that at the moment takes 3 CSVs (will likely make this an xlsx with multiple sheets), performs a function called maic (omitted for brevity) on the first 2 which essentially adds in an extra column called 'wt', then binds a subset of that joined data frame to the third CSV. I then call survfit() from the survival library on the joined data and try to plot it but I get this appearing in the app window:

> Error: could not find function "joinedData"

My code is below, it seems that survfit() just doesn't recognise that joinedData() exists even though I can render joinedData() in the app window so clearly it does. I'm sure it must be because of how I've defined the reactive expressions but I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work. Any help very gratefully received!

## Code (now edited to the solution)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput("ipdFile", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv")),
    fileInput("agdFile", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv")),
    fileInput("compdFile", NULL, accept = c(".csv", ".tsv")),
    tableOutput("ipd"),
    tableOutput("agd"),
    tableOutput("compd"),
    textOutput("key"),
    tableOutput("weightsd"),
    plotOutput("kmcurve")
    
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ipdData <- reactive({
        req(input$ipdFile)
        
        ext <- tools::file_ext(input$ipdFile$name)
        switch(ext,
               csv = vroom::vroom(input$ipdFile$datapath, delim = ","),
               tsv = vroom::vroom(input$ipdFile$datapath, delim = "\t"),
               validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
        )
    })
    
    agData <- reactive({
        req(input$agdFile)
        
        ext <- tools::file_ext(input$agdFile$name)
        switch(ext,
               csv = vroom::vroom(input$agdFile$datapath, delim = ","),
               tsv = vroom::vroom(input$agdFile$datapath, delim = "\t"),
               validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
        )
    })
    
    compData <- reactive({
        req(input$compdFile)
        
        ext <- tools::file_ext(input$agdFile$name)
        switch(ext,
               csv = vroom::vroom(input$compdFile$datapath, delim = ","),
               tsv = vroom::vroom(input$compdFile$datapath, delim = "\t"),
               validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv or .tsv file")
        )
    })
 # Reactive expressions  
    weightsData <- reactive({
        req(ipdData())
        req(agData())
        maic(
            ipd=ipdData(), 
            agd=agData()
        )
    })
    
    joinedData <- reactive({
        req(weightsData())
        req(compData())
        weightsData() %>% select('TRT', 
                                 'AVAL',
                                 'CNSR',
                                 'wt'
        ) %>%
            bind_rows(compData() %>% mutate(wt=1))
    })
    
    kmCurve <- reactive({
            req(joinedData())
            survfit(
            Surv(AVAL, CNSR)~TRT,
            weights=wt,
            data=joinedData() 
        )
    })
 
    # Outputs rendered to UI
           
    output$ipd <- renderTable({
        head(ipdData())
    })
    
    output$agd <- renderTable({
        head(agData())
    })
    
    
    output$weightsd <- renderTable({
        joinedData()
    })    
    
    output$kmcurve <- renderPlot({
        ggsurvplot(kmCurve(), 
                   data <- joinedData(),
                   combine=TRUE, 
                   title="Weighted KM curve",
                   risk.table=TRUE,
                   legend="none",
                   palette="lancet",
                   xlim=c(0,25),
                   break.time.by=1
        ) 
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I can't debug this properly without the UI part of your code. But I see that you refer to the reactive weightsData in your line of code "req(weightsData)". Maybe the missing brackets there might be your problem? - "req(weightsData())"

Comment: Sorry @olorcain, I just added the UI part, it's very simple for now I'm planning to add more once I get the server logic working. I just tried adding the brackets as you suggested but still no luck, same error message :-(

Comment: Hmm maybe survfit has its own environment, I don't really know the package survival.
Try to create an intermediary variable with joinedData, like this :

df <- joinedData()
survfit(
            Surv(AVAL, CNSR)~TRT,
            weights=wt,
            data=df
        )

Comment: Thanks @LeonIpdjian, I just tried that and got this error instead:
Error: 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list. 

Also if I insert a print statement within that reactive expression then I can print joinedData() to the console, so clearly it can be accessed from within that expression.

Comment: That's wierd... can you put browser() between req(joinedData()) and survfit( ? You will see the state of joinedData before the error.

Comment: Maybe joinedData() is empty at a moment and just returns a boolean.

Comment: Well, I'm almost sure that's the problem. If you add an req(is.data.frame(joinedData())) it should wold correctly.

Comment: Hi @LeonIpdjian, if I add that line in I still get an error- this is what I get from browser(): Called from: `<reactive:kmCurve>`(...)
Browse[1]> 
debug at #58: survfit(Surv(AVAL, CNSR) ~ TRT, weights = wt, data = joinedData())
Browse[2]> 
Warning: Error in joinedData: could not find function "joinedData"
  [No stack trace available]

Also I wonder if there are some clues on this thread? Although after reading this thread I still can't work it out:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-with-shiny-app-creation-and-output-in-r/45146/24

Comment: Within the browser(), try to evaluate joinedData() before clicking on next. Maybe you will see the error.

Yes, maybe your link will help you out !

Comment: It looks fine, exactly like it's supposed to (here's the first row below):

Browse[1]> joinedData()
        TRT   AVAL  CNSR          wt
1      Estimab   2.0    0 0.60997685

Comment: Even more weird, I can evaluate the survfit formula in browser!!! I am so so so confused :-(

Comment: Ok so it turns out if I just do a regular plot (not ggsurvplot) it works...So the problem is actually with the plotting not survfit...I haven't fixed it yet but I am at least a step closer!!

Comment: Right, solved! ggsurvplot was expecting a second argument, i.e. ggsurvplot(kmCurve(), data=joinedData()) works fine! Thanks @LeonIpdjian!

Comment: @TimothyReason great that you've solved your problem! Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, then others have it a bit easier to find it when they have the same problem :)

Comment: Good job ! :) Sometimes, R errors are not very explicit...

Comment: Thanks @starja have now edited the code so that it reflects the solution :-)